# Get the value of a field from an entity reference

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type (*Actuality*) with an entity reference field to another content type (*Event*). In the referenced content type, I have a *field_date* field I want to print in the *node--actuality.html.twig* template file. I tried using  `{{ node.field_event_associated.field_date }}`, but it doesn't work.

How can I print the field value of a referenced entity?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've posted this question, but I found this post: [Getting Drupal 8 Field Values in Twig](https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-drupal-8-field-values-in-twig-22b80cb609bd).

Answer (score 16):

With a *field_event_associated* node field, you can get its value with  `{{ node.field_event_associated.value }}`. That doesn't work for entity reference fields, for which you need to use `{{   node.field_event_associated.entity.field_date.value }}`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.
I don't manage to access my values like this, the only thing i can do is :
`{{ content.field_evenement_associe[0]['#url'].options['entity'].field_date_event.value }}` but i find it very complicated. Do i miss something ?

Comment: If you apply the example from this answer you get a shorter version:  `{{ node.field_event_associated.entity.field_date.value }}`.

Comment: Thanks i get some results with this version. By the way, where can i find this in Drupal doc ? Regards

Comment: You can find it in twig template documentation of drupal 8.

Comment: It will show you the first value, How will get the All value available in entity reference fields

Comment: Use `for` to loop through multi-value entity references. Inside the loop you can use the exact format listed in this answer:

`{% for item in node.field_paragraphs %}{{ item.entity.field_title.value }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: @ManmeetKhurana {{ content.field_event_associated.0 }}, should show you the all fields.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to **render a properly formatted single field of a referenced entity** you'll simply have to use the **|view** filter on the desired field of the referenced node.

Let's say the `field_customer` on my parent node references a customer content type entity that holds the customer's address in `field_address`.

```
{{ node.field_customer.entity.field_address|view }}
```

Use the referenced entity's display settings to define the format of the field you want to render.

[Example on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-12-16/entity-reference-values-in-twig-template#comment-13153259)

Answer (score 2):

The value you're mostly looking for would be the title value:

```
{{ node.field_organisation_reference.entity.title.value }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Output entity reference field value and create url on twig.

entity reference value : {{ node.field_name.entity.title.value }}

entity reference url : {{ url('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.field_name.target_id}) }}