# Calling entity reference field in page template

Tags: 8, theming

We are working on Drupal 8 Blog Page template. We want to render entity reference fields in the page template.

I have tried `{{ node.field_name.entity.name.value }}` and `{{ node.field_name.entity.uri.value }}` but none of this is working. Do I need to update/change anything in Drupal backend for the content type?

Answer (score 3):

The entity reference field normally contains just the entity ID as value.

Looking at [Twig get value of field in entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/222732/15055) and [Drupal 8 loop entity reference fields.twig](https://gist.github.com/frankyonnetti/39ef8984acfca879d16d8a4890095bb9) it seems a bit that

```
{{ node.field_name.entity }}
```

or

```
{{ node.field_name.0.entity }}
```

or

```
{{ node.field_name[0].entity }}
```

might work.

---

If it doesn't work, try [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) which gives you some [handy functions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x) to print Drupal entities in Twig.

```
{% set nid = node.field_name.target_id %}
{{ drupal_entity('node', nid) }}
```

Or even easier as recommended by @4k4 in the comments:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'node') }}
```

---

> Twig Tweak is a small module which provides a Twig extension with some
>   useful functions and filters that can improve development experience.

Comment: In the last example the nid is in `node.field_name.target_id`. If you have Twig Tweak installed there is any easier option. You can render any field with `{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'node') }}`. If you don't specify a node id it uses the current node, so this works in other templates as well.