# When will doctrine ORM be implemented for modules?

Tags: database

I am looking at Drupal for some websites I want to set up. I have been a Symfony developer in the past so would like to use doctrine when I create a custom module. Is it implemented in 9 dev yet? Any idea of when 9 will be at a stable version? Or will it not be implemented until a future version of 9?

Comment: Why? What advantage is that over the core Entity system?

Comment: I know Doctrine already.

Comment: This isn't something that is necessarily answerable in the long term. If we want change, we try to put it into action via the issue queue. I started a vague meta issue to decide what to do about [Drupal's database abstraction layer](https://www.drupal.org/project/ideas/issues/2846366). But also from there a couple of other links: [Consider using Doctrine ORM for Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1817778) and [Doctrine module](https://drupal.org/project/doctrine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 9 is [planned for some time in 2020](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/9). No, Doctrine ORM is not in a 9.x-dev branch.

As far as implementing, there are no immediate plans for it. D8 has its own [custom DBAL](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/database-api-overview), utilizing PHP PDO, and it's own custom ORM via its [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api).

Doctrine has [been proposed as a replacement](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1817778) but it's not an easy undertaking so don't expect it any time soon. Pre-existing DBAL/ORM components don't get replaced quickly.

If you want to utilize Doctrine ORM or DBAL, there are existing module projects out there that implement it. You're better off utilizing those projects or the Drupal Entity API (if your objects are managed content) than waiting for it to show up in D9

Comment: In Symfony you can load a particular entity, and it automatically loads any linked entities. For example if I load a student, than classes and teachers will be loaded, and I can access them in TWIG. In Drupal, will it load linked entities automatically and can I access them directly in TWIG?

Comment: Drupal entities are linked via entity reference fields. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222732/twig-get-value-of-field-in-entity-reference on using referenced entities in TWIG.