# Get the value of Entity reference revisions field in order email twig file

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to get the entity reference field value in order email.

Name of the entity reference is  `field_price_value` and called paragraph field is `field_price` now I want to get the field price value
I tried below method but none work for me

```
 order_entity.field_price_value.field_price.value

 {% for order_item in order_entity.getItems %}

{{ order_item.getPurchasedEntity.getfield_price_value.getfield_price

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would do it like this (if I'm understanding your scenario correctly):

```
{{ node.field_price_value.entity.field_price.value }}
```

Also this question has been asked and responded to before, you may find this helpful: [Twig get value of field in entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222732/twig-get-value-of-field-in-entity-reference)

Good luck!