# How to get node object from entity referance in paragraph twig template

Tags: theming

I created a content type named "programs", with an image, short description field.
Then I created a paragraph type and added a field as entity reference of programs.

Now in the paragraph twig template or in the field twig template, how can I get the value of image, and short description field?

In the field paragraph twig template

```
item.content
```

has only title and node id.

Comment: This question has been asked and responded to before, you may find this helpful: [Twig get value of field in entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222732/get-the-value-of-a-field-from-an-entity-reference) Good luck!

Comment: got it, thank you